# How to remove spaces between Touchable Opacity components in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

**Problem:**

I have created a react native component with three touchable opacity components. It is showing like this.

[image]

This is how my code is looking.

```
/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import LangaugeCard from './LanguageCard';
import styles from '_styles/homescreen';

class Localization extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.localization_container}>
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <LangaugeCard language="Hindi" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <LangaugeCard language="English"  />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <LangaugeCard language="French" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Localization;
```

My LanguageCard looks like this.

```
/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';
import styles from '_styles/homescreen';

const LanguageCard = (props) => {
  const {language, instruction} = props;
  return (
    <View style={styles.langauge_card}>
      <View style={styles.langauge_view}>
        <Text style={styles.language}>{language}</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.instruction_view}>
        <Text style={styles.instruction}>{instruction}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default LanguageCard;
```

This is my styling file.

```
/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: 'column',
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#eeeeee',
    height: '100%',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  localization_container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  langauge_card: {
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    height: '46%',
    marginLeft: '5%',
    marginRight: '5%',
    borderRadius:35,
    flexDirection:'row',
    elevation: 1,
  },
  langauge_view:{
    backgroundColor:'#007aff',
    marginTop: '8%',
    marginBottom: '8%',
    marginLeft:'8%',
    borderRadius: 15,
    width:'30%',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  language:{
    fontFamily:'IskoolaPota',
    fontSize:24,
    textAlign:'center',
    color:'#ffffff',
    justifyContent:'center',
  },
  instruction_view:{
    marginTop: '8%',
    marginBottom: '8%',
    marginLeft:'5%',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  instruction:{
    color:'#444444',
    fontSize: 15,
  },
});

export default styles;
```

What I want to do is to reduce the space between touchable components and put all three buttons center of the screen I tried a lot to find a way to do so but It was unable to do so. Can someone help me to achieve this one by modifying the code? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I don't think its a good idea to use percentages as height in this case. Right now, your TouchableOpacity is going off the screen because you have `height: '46%',` Since you have 3 of those, its height is 138% + padding and margins.

I prefer to use flex and use `justifyContent` for aligning horizontally and `align-items` for aligning vertically

So in your case,

```
langauge_card:{
 flex: 1,
}
langauge_view:{
 flex: 1,
 alignItems: "center",
 justifyContent: "center"
}
instruction_view:{
 flex: 1,
 alignItems: "center",
 justifyContent: "center"
}
```

You can play around wth flex, margin, and "flex-start", "center", "flex-end" for justify content and alignItem.

Hope this helped a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Put these styles in `localization_container`

```
  { 
   flex: 1,
   alignItems: 'center',
   JustifyContent: 'center'
  }
```

These styles will make sure items inside the child's view will be `shown in the center` of the screen then remove the hight of your containers (if you have any) one by one, Try to avoid usage of `%` as this can unpredictable.